# Explain a reason of forbidding dirty-write

Tags: transactions, isolation-level, ansi-sql

Snippets from [A Critique of ANSI SQL Isolation Levels](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr-95-51.pdf) about reasons of forbidding dirty writes (P0).

Dirty writes:

> Transaction T1 modifies a data item. Another transaction T2 then
> further modifies that data item before T1 performs a COMMIT or
> ROLLBACK. If T1 or T2 then performs a ROLLBACK, it is unclear what the
> correct data value should be.

A reason:

> As discussed in [GLPT, BHG] and elsewhere, automatic transaction
> rollback is another pressing reason why P0 is important. Without
> protection from P0, the system can’t undo updates by restoring before
> images. Consider the history: w1[x] w2[x] a1. You don’t want to undo
> w1[x] by restoring its before-image of x, because that would wipe out
> w2’s update. But if you don’t restore its before-image, and
> transaction T2 later aborts, you can’t undo w2[x] by restoring its
> before-image either!

My question is why can’t we undo w2[x] by restoring its before-image in this case? Does it mean that each transaction doesn't store its individual before-image (of value x)? Then what's T2's before-image? Is it  w1[x] (the value of X before w2[x])? Could anyone describe this case in details?
I know, that dirty write is not a real case, but nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is during any abort, auto-rollback restores to its before image. So consider: w1[x] w2[x]a1, if T1 rolls back to before w1[x] then on commit of T2, it’s val will be lost; and if T1 rolls back to w2[x] and then T2 aborts, it can’t set the value to its preimage as it was w1[x] but T1 was already aborted so it would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of history `w1[x] w2[x] a1`,

If `t1` has rollbacked and restored before-image of `w1[x]`, then `w2[x]` update value will be wiped out because `t1` aborts after `w2[x]`.

But, if `t1` has not rollbacked in order to preserve the `w2[x]` update value, then later if `t2` aborts, its before-image will be the update value by `w1[x]` which should have been rollbacked.